# java Singleton - prevent multiple creation through reflection

Tags: java, singleton

I have a singleton like this.

```
public class BookingFactory {

    private final static BookingFactory instance;

    static {
        instance = new BookingFactory();
    }

    public static BookingFactory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private BookingFactory() {
        System.out.println("Object is created.");
    }
}

public class Test  {
    BookingFactory instance = BookingFactory.getInstance();
    instance = BookingFactory.getInstance();

    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.test.BookingFactory");

    Constructor pvtConstructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];

    // Set its access control
    pvtConstructor.setAccessible(true);

    // Invoke Private Constructor
    BookingFactory notSingleton = (BookingFactory) pvtConstructor.newInstance(null);
}
```

When I run this, I saw more than one printout message. Is there any way to prevent this singleton from being instantiated more than once from this reflection?

Thanks.

Comment: The real question is why you would be so concerned with preventing it? If a programmer is going to that amount of trouble then it would mean they intend to reverse engineer the singleton in some manner to suite some special case that wasn't considered during design. Not saying it would be the most brilliant idea, but at the same time, this is all hypothetical anyways.

Comment: +1 Really well presented question, especially the [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)

Answer (score 16):

Try using an `enum`. enums make for good Singletons.

```
public static enum BookingFactory {
    INSTANCE;
    public static BookingFactory getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

You can't create an enum via reflection.

The getInstance() method is superfluous but makes it easier to run your test, throwing the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot reflectively create enum objects
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:530)
    at MultiSingletonTest.main(MultiSingletonTest.java:40)
```

Oh look, someone already gave the enum answer. Posting anyway for more completeness.

Comment: I was going back and forth on just voting to cloase as a duplicate. It probably should be.

Comment: they should probably automatically close-as-duplicate to any Java question containing the word singleton but not enum ;)

Comment: enum cannot inherit. Sometimes we want a Singleton to inherit from another class, for example java.util.Observable.

Answer (score 14):

Make the assertion in the constructor:

```
private BookingFactory() {
    if (instance != null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Only one instance may be created");
    System.out.println("Object is created.");
}
```

Comment: @Kaunteya yes, when used with code in the question, it is threadsafe, because `instance` is created in a static block it executes at class loading time (not lazy initialized) and the class loader has its own thread safety built in. The JVM guarantees that all static initialization will be complete before the class can be used, which includes calling constructors.

Answer (score 11):

Adapted from [Making the Java Singleton Reflection Proof when using Lazy Loading](http://technonstop.com/java-singleton-reflection-and-lazy-initialization):

```
package server;

import java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission;
import java.security.*;


public class JavaSingleton {

  private static JavaSingleton INSTANCE = null;

  private JavaSingleton() {
    ReflectPermission perm = new ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks", "");
    AccessController.checkPermission(perm); 
  }


  synchronized public static final JavaSingleton getInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
      AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
        public Object run() {
          INSTANCE= new JavaSingleton();
          return null;
        }
      });
    }
    return INSTANCE;
  }
```

The constructor has a check to see if the caller has access to it. As the link explains, a policy file that permits the Singleton class itself to call the constructor will need to be created.

Bohemian's method of throwing an exception does not prevent a client from reflectively calling the constructor before getInstance() is called. Even though it ensures that only one instance gets created, there's no guarantee that this is done by the Singleton class' `getInstance()` method.

The access control check will prevent this unwanted instantiation.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend reading [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java/71399#71399) - using an enum prevents what you're describing and is the recommended way to implement a singleton in java.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Singleton implements Serializable,Cloneable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static  Singleton singleton=null;
//private static volatile Singleton singleton=null;
private Singleton() {
    if(singleton!=null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Its Singleton Class use getInstance method for object creation");
    }
}

public static Singleton getInstance(){
    return Holder.singleton;

}

/****
 * good way for getting the instance. No need to worry about 
 * BillPughSingleton
 */
private static class Holder{
    private static final Singleton singleton=new Singleton();
}

/***
/*
 * Use this code for preventing Singleton breakage in multi threading scenario and comment above getInstance method
 * As this is the efficient way
 * If we put synchronized at method level level then will impact performance and will executed every time when getInstance is called
 * But if once the instance is created then there is no need for synchronized.
 */

/*  public static Singleton getInstance(){
    if(singleton==null){
        synchronized (Singleton.class) {
            if(singleton==null){
                singleton=new Singleton();
            }
        }

    }
    return singleton;

}*/

@Override
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    /***
     * We can place below check OR we can remove the exception thrown check and return  singleton instead of super.clone()
     * Use any one way
     */
    if(singleton!=null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Its Singleton Class use getInstance method for object creation");
    }
    return super.clone(); 
}
/***
 * 
 * To Prevent breaking of singleton pattern by using serilization/de serilization
 */
private Object readResolve(){
    System.out.println("Read Resolve executed");
    return singleton;
}
}
```

** Testing singleton**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/***
 * 
 * Ways to prevent break Singleton
 */
public class Main {

private static ObjectInputStream inputStream;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Singleton orginalSingletonObject = Singleton.getInstance();

    /***
     * Singleton is broken by using Reflection
     * We can prevent that by putting a check in private constructor of Singleton.java
     * 
     */
    breakSingletonByReflection(orginalSingletonObject);

    /***
     * By Serialization/De-Serialization break Singleton We need
     * Serialization interface in a class needs to be serialized like
     * Singleton.java
     * 
     * To prevent breaking of singleton we can add readResolve method in Singleton.java
     * readResolve is the method which returns the instance of the class when a serialized class is de serialized. 
     * So implement the readResolve method to return the same object. 
     *  Hence prevent breaking of Singleton design pattern.
     *  Refer this link for more information on readResolve 
     *  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#5903
     */
    breakSingletonByserialization(orginalSingletonObject);

    /***
     * By Cloning break Singleton
     * We need to implement Cloneable interface
     * We can prevent that by putting a check in clone method of Singleton.java
     */
    breakSingletonByCloning(orginalSingletonObject);


    /***
     * Break Singleton By thread
     * This scenario is related to multi-threading environment
     * We can do this by putting double lock mechanism in Singleton.java and its good practice to use Volatile
     * We can also prevent this scenario of breaking by creating object eagerly but its not good to create object eagerly
     */

    breakSingletonByThreading(orginalSingletonObject);
}

private static void breakSingletonByThreading(Singleton orginalSingletonObject) {

    ExecutorService executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    /**
     * Run this code snippet after commenting the other code for better understanding
     * Run it repeatly to create a condition when 2 threads enter the method getInstance() of Singleton class at a same time 
     * When 2 threads enter the getInstance method at same time they will get the singleton object as null (private static Singleton singleton in Singleton.java)
     * Then they will create two different objects ( have different hashcode) in this case singleton pattern will break.
     */
    executorService.submit(Main::useSingleton); // JAVA 8 syntax it will get the singleton instance
    executorService.submit(Main::useSingleton);
    executorService.shutdown();
}

public static void useSingleton(){
    Singleton singleton=Singleton.getInstance();
    printSingletonData("By Threading", singleton);

}




private static void breakSingletonByCloning(Singleton orginalSingletonObject) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Singleton clonedSingletonObject=(Singleton) orginalSingletonObject.clone();
    printSingletonData("By Cloning", orginalSingletonObject, clonedSingletonObject);
}

private static void breakSingletonByReflection(Singleton orginalsingleton)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException {

    Class<?> singletonClass = Class.forName("SingletonTest.Singleton");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Constructor<Singleton> constructor = (Constructor<Singleton>) singletonClass
            .getDeclaredConstructor();
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    Singleton s = constructor.newInstance();
    printSingletonData("By Reflection", orginalsingleton, s);
}

private static void breakSingletonByserialization(Singleton orginalsingleton)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    /**
     * Serialization
     */
    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("E:\\Singleton.ser"));
    outputStream.writeObject(orginalsingleton);
    outputStream.close();

    /**
     * DeSerialization
     */
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("E:\\Singleton.ser"));

    Singleton deserializeObject = (Singleton) inputStream.readObject();
    deserializeObject.hashCode();
    printSingletonData("By Serialization", orginalsingleton, deserializeObject);


}

public static void printSingletonData(String operationName,
        Singleton orginalsingleton, Singleton reflectionSigletonObject) {

    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("New Operation");
    System.out.println(operationName);
    System.out.println("orginal Hashcode=" + orginalsingleton.hashCode());
    System.out.println("New Object hashcode="
            + reflectionSigletonObject.hashCode());
    Boolean value = orginalsingleton.hashCode() != reflectionSigletonObject.hashCode();
    System.out.println("These Object have different hascode. They are two different object Right = "
                    + value);
    System.out.println("As these are different Object this means Singleton Pattern is broken");
}


private static void printSingletonData(String operationName,Singleton singleton) {


    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("New Operation");
    System.out.println(operationName);
    System.out.println("Object hashcode="   + singleton.hashCode());
    //System.out.println("As these are different Object this means Singleton Pattern is broken");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your singleton does not actually store state, then your best option is to not use a singleton.  Instead, implement the factory as a static state-free method.