# Java: Singleton, IODH idiom and reflection attack

Tags: java, reflection, singleton

Disclaimer: this is a question meant as an intellectual exercise, hence I do not want to use Enum here.

With reference to my previous question:
[Java: Lazy loading Singleton and reflection attack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138222/java-lazy-loading-singleton-and-reflection-attack)

Following is a solution I came up with to prevent reflection attack for IODH idiom. Could you pl. comment on the solution and suggest other approaches? 
(I'm aware of 'permission' approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8112238/266103)

Again, *this code is meant strictly as an intellectual exercise, and I would never use anything like this in real life*.

Also 1) this code creates two instances but retains the second if the instance is created through constructor reflection instead of calling `getInstance()` and, 2) it is unlikely to be thread-safe.

```
public class Singleton 
{
    private volatile static boolean isCreated = false;

    private static class Holder
    {
        private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }

    private Singleton()
    {               
        if(isCreated)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Singleton Multiple Instantiation");
        }       
        Holder.instance = this;
        isCreated = true;
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance()
    {
        return Holder.instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: - What stops attacker from setting the `isCreated` flag to false and do what ever he/she wants? - `isCreated` flag could be replaced by just `Singleton.Holder.instance != null`

Comment: Good point about #1. Any suggestions on how to fix it?                                   For #2, that's the first thing I tried, but then I found out that it won't work if you create the instance through constructor reflection first.